# Text automatically moves to accommodate animated adjacent text (jquery): How to smoothen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation

I'm cycling through words using jquery. Naturally, the word size varies causing the non-animated text next to it to shift out of position. Is there a way to smoothen this shift in position?

What I have: http://jsfiddle.net/tWm36/121/

What I'm trying to acheive: https://gumroad.com/

See how the text moves smoothly away to accommodate the words being cycled, instead of one sudden movement?

```
<div>
<span id="changerificwordspanid">awesome</span>
 <span>This is so</span>
```

```
(function(){
var words = [
    'awesome',
    'incredible',
    'cool',
    'fantastic'
    ], i = 0;
setInterval(function(){
    $('#changerificwordspanid').fadeOut(function(){
        $(this).html(words[i=(i+1)%words.length]).fadeIn();
    });
}, 2000);

})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/tWm36/126/)!

```
<div> 
   <div id='words' style='visibility:hidden'>
       <span>awesome</span>
       <span>incredible</span>
       <span>cool</span>
       <span>fantastic</span>
   </div>

   <span id="changerificwordspanid" style='overflow-x:hidden'>awesome</span>
   <span>This is so</span>
</div>
```

I've created hidden spans containing the text. This allows you to get the browser-calculated width. We will animate the width of the displayed span as we fade in the text. Setting `overflow-x:hidden` on the displayed span is important as it allows the width to be less than the width of the text. Using fadeOut() isn't quite right as we don't want to set display:none at any point, as this will cause jerky behaviour. So just use animate() like so:

```
(function () {
    var words = $('#words span').map(function(i, obj) { return { width: $(obj).width() + 'px', text: $(obj).html() } });

    var i = 0;
    setInterval(function () {
        $('#changerificwordspanid').animate({ opacity: 0.0, width: words[i].width }, 
                                            400, function () {
            word = words[i = (i + 1) % words.length];
            $(this).html(word.text);
            $(this).animate({ opacity: 1.0, width: word.width });
        });
    }, 2000);

})();
```

Comment: It's very possible that this could be shrunk down but this is the basic idea.

Comment: Whoops, I'd removed the overflow-x:hidden accidentally. Super smooth again now.

Comment: You could absolutely just get the old width before calling $(this).html(...), then get the new width, set the width immediately after, then animate up to the correct width for the text--no need for the hidden spans, then.

Comment: This works great! I really appreciate you taking the time to explain. Cheers!

Comment: why is the very first transition still jerky, but the rest are fine?

Comment: Looks like we need to set the width of that span in the first iteration, e.g.  $('#changerificwordspanid').animate({ opacity: 0.0, width: words[i].width } ...

Comment: Ah i see. Is it possible to apply this to sandwich a stationary word? ie: (animated-text) stationary-text (animated-text)

Comment: I'm out now, but consider applying it to a few words in a sentence and then centering the sentence in some container.